# SQLAlchemy python how to execute raw query?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I am trying to execute raw query using sqlchemy and python but getting error. Everywhere i saw similar example. Below is my code

```
import sqlalchemy.pool as pool
import psycopg2
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import os
load_dotenv()


def getconn():
    c = psycopg2.connect(user=os.getenv('POSTGRES_USER'), password = os.getenv('POSTGRES_PASSWORD'),  host=os.getenv('POSTGRES_HOST'), port=os.getenv('DATABASE_PORT'), dbname=os.getenv('POSTGRES_DB'))
    return c


mypool = pool.QueuePool(getconn, max_overflow=10, pool_size=5)


def get_connection():
    conn = mypool.connect()
    return conn.cursor()

# use it
db = get_connection()
print(db)
output = db.execute("select 2+2 as sum")
print(output.fetchone())
```

Getting error

```
<cursor object at 0x0000021B18795C40; closed: 0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\gourav.kumar\code\genai_ozone_engine\genai_ozone_engine\app\database\database.py", line 25, in <module>
    print(output.fetchone())
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'fetchone'
```

SQLAlchemy==2.0.14

how to get output for database raw query?

Comment: reference link - https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/pooling.html

Comment: you should not assign it to `output`, instead do it like so `db.execute("select 2+2 as sum")` then do `output = db.fetchone()`